# How to conditionally halt evaluation of child reactive expressions in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Consider the following minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = basicPage(
        actionButton("button", "click"),
        textOutput("text"),
        textOutput("valid")
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        parent <- reactive({
            2*input$button
        })
        child1 <- reactive({
            Sys.sleep(1)  # expensive function
            parent() + 1
        })
        child2 <- reactive({
            Sys.sleep(1)  # expensive function
            parent() + 2
        })
        child3 <- reactive({
            Sys.sleep(1)  # expensive function
            parent() + 3
        })

        output$text <- renderText(
            paste(
                "The meaning of life (for even input only):",
                child1() * child2() * child3()
            )
        )
        output$valid <- renderText(
            ifelse(
                input$button %% 2 == 0,
                "Valid - even input!",
                "Invalid - odd input! I don't want anything to have been re-rendered!"
            )
        )
    }
))
```

**If the user specifies an invalid input** (i.e. `input$button` is odd), **I don't want the page to be re-rendered**. In particular, child reactive expressions could contain expensive functions which I don't want to execute if the inputs are invalid.

Also, I might have hundreds of child expressions -- I really don't want to have to put input validation code in each one.

What can be done?

Comment: what about a stop() in parent() on bad input ??

Comment: @KarlForner thanks, I tried but throwing an error wipes out all my output widgets. Red error text displays in place of every widget that depends on the input in question - I was hoping to be able to handle errors with my own custom code in a more graceful manner.

Comment: I guess you could define function good_input(), on which you will condition in each function, e.g.  child1 <- reactive({ if (good_input() { Sys.sleep(1); parent() +1})